# Проверить список(vector) на наличие класса с определенной строкой

Tags: c++, vector

Всем привет, у меня есть класс, назовем его `CommandExecutor`, у которого есть строка, которая возвращает имя этой команды. Все эти команды я храню в списке `vector` и мне нужно проверить, содержит ли `vector` команду с тем или иным именем.

```
class CommandExecutor {
private:
    string name;
public:
    CommandExecutor(const string& name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    const string getName() {
        return this->name;
    }
};

class Test {
private:
    vector<CommandExecutor*> commands;
public:
    void test() {
        commands.push_back(new CommandExecutor("Test1"));
        commands.push_back(new CommandExecutor("Test21"));
        //И тут дальше надо проверить этот список на наличие команды с именем Test1 или же иным именем
    }
};
```

Есть предположение, что можно проверить через `find_if`, но я в этом не уверен. Как-то до этого выкручивался, используя цикл, но сейчас хочу упросить весь этот процесс.
И еще хотел бы узнать кое-что. В `Java` есть такой метод у строки, как `startsWith`, с помощью которого можно проверить начало строки на тот же префикс например. Есть ли подобная реализация в `C++`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find + https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with

Comment: @dIm0n, по поводу метода `find` уже читал, но все равно не понял, как реализовать его у себя. А метод `starts_with` у меня отсутствует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
bool startsWith(string str, string with) {
    return str.substr(0, with.length()) == with;
}

bool contains(vector<CommandExecutor*> commands, string name) {
    return find_if(commands.begin(), commands.end(), 
          [&](CommandExecutor* com1) { return com1->getName() == name; }) != commands.end();
}
```